# Проблема с #define

Tags: c++, visual-c++, макросы

Почему неработоспособен вот этот код:

```
 #define NUM 10;
 size_t d = 1;
 size_t bufferSize = NUM * d;
```

Ошибка в последней строке "Операнд * должен быть указателем".

Comment: Уберите точку с запятой после  `#define NUM 10;`

Answer (score 2):

Уберите точку с запятой после `#define`

```
 #define NUM 10
 size_t d = 1;
 size_t bufferSize = NUM * d;
```